# Display names of col 1 having the same col 2 in at least two col 3s from a three-column many-to-many table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a question about SQL Server query.

The tables can be described as following:

- **Suppliers** (`SID, sName, status, sCity`), PK = SID
- **Parts** (`PID, pName, color, weight, pCity`), PK = PID
- **Projects** (`JID, jName, city`), PK = JID
- **SPJ** (`SID, PID, JID, quantity`), PK = (SID, PID, JID), FK = SID, PID, JID

I am trying to get supplier numbers and names for suppliers of the same part to at least two projects, here is my query for the task:

```
SELECT 
    s1.SID, s1.sName, COUNT(*)
FROM 
    Suppliers s1, Parts p, SPJ s2
WHERE 
    s1.SID = s2.SID 
    AND p.PID = s2.PID 
GROUP BY 
    s1.SID, s1.sName
HAVING 
    COUNT(*)>1
ORDER BY 
    s1.SID, s1.sName
```

Please help me correct this query. Thank you in advance

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**20 years** ago!). ***Please*** stop using it

Answer (score 2):

This does exactly what you ask:

```
SELECT
   S.SupplierID,
   S.sName
FROM
   dbo.Suppliers S
WHERE
   EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM dbo.SPJ SPJ
      WHERE S.SupplierID = SPJ.SupplierID
      GROUP BY SPJ.PartID
      HAVING Count(*) >= 2
   );
```

[Please see my SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6dc98/5) to try it out on a real data set. Note there is also a query showing all the individual rows that participate to make a supplier qualify (see the `Qualifies` column). Here is a preview of the setup script:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Suppliers (
   SupplierID smallint identity(1,1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Suppliers PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   sName varchar(40) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT UQ_Suppliers_sName UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Parts (
   PartID int identity(1,1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Parts PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   pName varchar(100) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT UQ_Parts_pName UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Projects (
   ProjectID int identity(1,1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Projects PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   jName varchar(50) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT UQ_Projects_jName UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.SPJ (
   SupplierID smallint NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_SPJ_Suppliers FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Suppliers (SupplierID),
   PartID int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_SPJ_Parts FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Parts (PartID),
   ProjectID int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_SPJ_Projects FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Projects (ProjectID),
   CONSTRAINT PK_SPJ PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (SupplierID, PartID, ProjectID)
);

INSERT dbo.Suppliers
VALUES
   ('Joe'' Specialty Goods'),
   ('Major Supplier'),
   ('Small Supplier'),
   ('Tamandua Manufacturing, Ltd.'),
   ('Things ''n'' Stuff'),
   ('Stuff ''n'' Things');

INSERT dbo.Parts
VALUES
   ('Watchamacallit'),
   ('Thingamajiggy'),
   ('Thingamabob'),
   ('Doohickey'),
   ('Whatsisname'),
   ('Thingy'),
   ('Gizmo'),
   ('Gadget'),
   ('Widget'),
   ('Titanium Widget'),
   ('Electronic Thingamabob'),
   ('One-Product Patrick');

INSERT dbo.Projects
VALUES
   ('Video Game Manufacturing'),
   ('Autodoc Research'),
   ('Consumer Electronics Expansion'),
   ('Space Shuttle'),
   ('Tablet Project Cobalt');

INSERT dbo.SPJ
VALUES
   (1, 2, 1),
   (1, 3, 1),
   (1, 7, 1),
   (1, 11, 1),
   (2, 1, 1),
   (2, 1, 2),
   (2, 1, 3),
   (2, 1, 4),
   (2, 2, 1),
   (2, 2, 2),
   (2, 2, 3),
   (2, 2, 4),
   (2, 2, 5),
   (2, 10, 1),
   (2, 10, 2),
   (2, 10, 3),
   (2, 10, 4),
   (2, 10, 5),
   (3, 5, 4),
   (4, 4, 2),
   (4, 4, 3),
   (5, 9, 1),
   (5, 8, 2),
   (5, 7, 3),
   (5, 6, 4),
   (5, 5, 5),
   (6, 1, 1),
   (6, 2, 1),
   (6, 3, 1),
   (6, 4, 1),
   (6, 5, 1),
   (6, 6, 1),
   (6, 7, 1),
   (6, 8, 1),
   (6, 9, 1),
   (6, 10, 1),
   (6, 11, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SID, PID, COUNT(JID)
FROM SPJ
GROUP BY SID, PID
HAVING COUNT(JID) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it like this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
a.SupplierID,
b.sName
FROM
(
  SELECT
   SupplierID,
   PartID,
   NumProjects = count(DISTINCT ProjectID)
  FROM SPJ
  GROUP BY
   SupplierID, PartID
  HAVING 
   count(DISTINCT ProjectID) >= 2 
) a
INNER JOIN Suppliers b ON a.SupplierID = b.SupplierID
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT Supplier.SID,Supplier.sName
FROM SPJ inner join Supplier on SPJ.SID = Supplier.SID
inner join Parts on SPJ.PID = Parts.PID
GROUP BY Supplier.SID,Supplier.sName
HAVING COUNT(JID) > 1
```

Comment: This is incorrect. It is returning a row for every supplier who has ever supplied more than one part, even if all parts were for the same project.